# Connect USB hard drive to wireless router on RJ45 port? Possible?

Tags: hard-drive, wireless-networking, usb, router

just a quick story behind. I was trying to set up wireless networked hard drive at home. My wireless router doesn't take USB. I am considering few options.

First i was considering to get something like [WD My Cloud](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=1140). My router is an old one provided by service provider. It only has 10/100 Ethernet. WD My Cloud has Gigabit interface. So unless i changed a new router, data transfer will be slow.

So upgrading the router is a must if i want fast transfer speed. Plus I already own an external hard drive with USB 3.0 interface. So if I get a router like [Netgear D6300](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/R6250.aspx#tab-techspecs), i can get a decent speed wireless shared drive at home. And i can use my existing HDD instead of WD My Cloud. But the router isn't cheap so I am saving up for that.

In the meantime I found out the existence of [USB to RJ45 adaptor](http://www.amazon.co.uk/RJ45-Ethernet-100Mb-Network-Adapter/dp/B000MHO3Q8). I read the reviews and some say it works for them and for some don't. They didn't really say what they were trying to do so I'm confused.

So if i bought an adaptor like this, can i connect my existing HDD (USB) with my existing router (RJ45) and use it as a shared drive for data transfer? I know it will be slow as the adaptor will only have USB 2.0 and 10/100 for Ethernet. But it's fine as it's for temporary until i got my new router.

[image]

Comment: I have a Sharkoon Lanport 400, which works OK on WinXP: it has four USB ports, but requires manual installation with the support utility each time a device is connected or removed. There is no OS support for other than Windows, but I have accessed a connected drive from Ubuntu using network sharing, which I think is also required for multiple Windows clients.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those adapters will almost certainly not work. They look like they will simply use a USB cable to send the signal from an RJ45, not CONVERT USB to Ethernet (what you are trying to achieve).

There are a couple of solutions to your query:

1. Get one of those WD My Cloud devices, as you have said - this will also enable your device to be accessible from the Internet easily;
2. Upgrade your router to include a USB mass storage capability - I wouldn't hold your hopes up it being USB 3.0, however;
3. Set up a computer on your network that is on all the time and "share" the drive. Or;
4. Get a USB to NAS device. This might be your saviour.

Comment: Thanks Chris .. I obviously didn't think of option 3 and i don't really know what is USB to NAS device. could you have a link to one of those devices?

Comment: PC Mag did a comparison of such USB NASes: http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2392221,00.asp