# Create a NAS from an External Drive

Tags: networking

I have an external 1TB drive that I would like to use as a NAS. It has a USB B connection and my router (Virgin Superhub 3) only has Ethernet ports. I don't think I can just find an adaptor and plug the HDD into the router, I think I may need some 'converter' of some sort in between?
Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't think about any USB-RJ45 converter, check this out: http://superuser.com/questions/766229/connect-usb-hard-drive-to-wireless-router-on-rj45-port-possible

Comment: Such a converter would be called a "NAS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be exactly what you want, but if you plug in the 1TB drive to a computer that's connected to the network and share the drive you can access it from anywhere as long as you're connected to the same network.

Comment: I agree. Furthermore, there are some routers with USB port and the capability of sharing the content of an USB drive connected to it.